# How to get Google to show the last modified time rather than first published time in news search results?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-news

I am working a news websites where we generally publish content regularly on a regular interval.  The problem is that when we updated the content, Google does not pick the last mod time. It shows the first published time.

Sharing with you an example URL with SERP;

Story URL: http://abpnews.abplive.in/television/kapil-sharma-is-coming-back-with-a-game-show-786242

SERP: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2+%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%89%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A1%E0%A5%80+%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8B+%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82+%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BF+%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AE+%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8B+%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5+%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%9B%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%9F%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0+%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%80&oq=%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2+%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%89%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A1%E0%A5%80+%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8B+%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82+%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BF+%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AE+%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8B+%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5+%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%9B%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%9F%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87+%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0+%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%80&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.1129j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The search results list it as "10 hours ago" for me.    That seems like it is picking up the recent modifications.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/so0iQ.png

Comment: Critical Strike... Worlds Longest URL.

Comment: No, when we published the URL. Google has taken the time of first published only.